# Ruby on Rails 5.0 upgrade not working with rails console or db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initialization, argument-error

After recently upgrading to Ruby on Rails 5.0 from 4.2, I have been unable to run rake db:migrate, or rails console.  I think it best to solve the console error first and it seems to give the followin more informative errors:

Here is the full stack trace if I correctly understand your request.  Thank you.

```
    $ rails c
    /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:49:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2) (ArgumentError)
        from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/draper-57a514133bc2/lib/draper/view_context/build_strategy.rb:41:in `new'
        from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/draper-57a514133bc2/lib/draper/view_context/build_strategy.rb:41:in `block in controller'
        from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/andand-1.3.3/lib/andand.rb:60:in `me'
        from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/draper-57a514133bc2/lib/draper/view_context/build_strategy.rb:40:in `controller'
        from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/draper-57a514133bc2/lib/draper/view_context/build_strategy.rb:30:in `call'
        from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/draper-57a514133bc2/lib/draper/view_context.rb:49:in `build'
        from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/draper-57a514133bc2/lib/draper/railtie.rb:63:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:226:in `block in run_console_blocks'
        from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:247:in `each'
        from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:247:in `each_registered_block'
        from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:226:in `run_console_blocks'
        from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:463:in `block in run_console_blocks'
        from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:13:in `each'
        from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:13:in `each'
        from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:463:in `run_console_blocks'
        from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:442:in `load_console'
        from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:34:in `initialize'
        from /Users/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-

--clipped 441 characters to enter stack overflow question edit
```

I understand that the test_case.rb part of the actionpack-5.0.0 gem expects two arguments.  After opening this code in Textmate I see the 'initialize' method is part of the TestRequest Class in the following test_case.rb file:

```
require 'rack/session/abstract/id'
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions'
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/to_query'
require 'active_support/core_ext/module/anonymous'
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/keys'
require 'action_controller/template_assertions'
require 'rails-dom-testing'

module ActionController
  # :stopdoc:
  class Metal
    include Testing::Functional
  end

  module Live
    # Disable controller / rendering threads in tests.  User tests can access
    # the database on the main thread, so they could open a txn, then the
    # controller thread will open a new connection and try to access data
    # that's only visible to the main thread's txn.  This is the problem in #23483
    remove_method :new_controller_thread
    def new_controller_thread # :nodoc:
      yield
    end
  end

  # ActionController::TestCase will be deprecated and moved to a gem in Rails 5.1.
  # Please use ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest going forward.
  class TestRequest < ActionDispatch::TestRequest #:nodoc:
    DEFAULT_ENV = ActionDispatch::TestRequest::DEFAULT_ENV.dup
    DEFAULT_ENV.delete 'PATH_INFO'

    def self.new_session
      TestSession.new
    end

    # Create a new test request with default `env` values
    def self.create
      env = {}
      env = Rails.application.env_config.merge(env) if defined?(Rails.application) && Rails.application
      env["rack.request.cookie_hash"] = {}.with_indifferent_access
      new(default_env.merge(env), new_session)
    end

    def self.default_env
      DEFAULT_ENV
    end
    private_class_method :default_env

    def initialize(env, session)
      super(env)

      self.session = session
      self.session_options = TestSession::DEFAULT_OPTIONS
      @custom_param_parsers = {
        xml: lambda { |raw_post| Hash.from_xml(raw_post)['hash'] }
      }
    end

    def query_string=(string)
      set_header Rack::QUERY_STRING, string
    end

    def content_type=(type)
      set_header 'CONTENT_TYPE', type
    end

    def assign_parameters(routes, controller_path, action, parameters, generated_path, query_string_keys)
      non_path_parameters = {}
      path_parameters = {}

      parameters.each do |key, value|
        if query_string_keys.include?(key)
          non_path_parameters[key] = value
        else
          if value.is_a?(Array)
            value = value.map(&:to_param)
          else
            value = value.to_param
          end

          path_parameters[key] = value
        end
      end

      if get?
        if self.query_string.blank?
          self.query_string = non_path_parameters.to_query
        end
      else
        if ENCODER.should_multipart?(non_path_parameters)
          self.content_type = ENCODER.content_type
          data = ENCODER.build_multipart non_path_parameters
        else
          fetch_header('CONTENT_TYPE') do |k|
            set_header k, 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          end

          case content_mime_type.to_sym
          when nil
            raise "Unknown Content-Type: #{content_type}"
          when :json
            data = ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(non_path_parameters)
          when :xml
            data = non_path_parameters.to_xml
          when :url_encoded_form
            data = non_path_parameters.to_query
          else
            @custom_param_parsers[content_mime_type.symbol] = ->(_) { non_path_parameters }
            data = non_path_parameters.to_query
          end
        end

        set_header 'CONTENT_LENGTH', data.length.to_s
        set_header 'rack.input', StringIO.new(data)
      end

      fetch_header("PATH_INFO") do |k|
        set_header k, generated_path
      end
      path_parameters[:controller] = controller_path
      path_parameters[:action] = action

      self.path_parameters = path_parameters
    end

    ENCODER = Class.new do
      include Rack::Test::Utils

      def should_multipart?(params)
        # FIXME: lifted from Rack-Test. We should push this separation upstream
        multipart = false
        query = lambda { |value|
          case value
          when Array
            value.each(&query)
          when Hash
            value.values.each(&query)
          when Rack::Test::UploadedFile
            multipart = true
          end
        }
        params.values.each(&query)
        multipart
      end

      public :build_multipart

      def content_type
        "multipart/form-data; boundary=#{Rack::Test::MULTIPART_BOUNDARY}"
      end
    end.new

    private

    def params_parsers
      super.merge @custom_param_parsers
    end
  end

  class LiveTestResponse < Live::Response
    # Was the response successful?
    alias_method :success?, :successful?

    # Was the URL not found?
    alias_method :missing?, :not_found?

    # Was there a server-side error?
    alias_method :error?, :server_error?
  end

  # Methods #destroy and #load! are overridden to avoid calling methods on the
  # @store object, which does not exist for the TestSession class.
  class TestSession < Rack::Session::Abstract::SessionHash #:nodoc:
    DEFAULT_OPTIONS = Rack::Session::Abstract::Persisted::DEFAULT_OPTIONS

    def initialize(session = {})
      super(nil, nil)
      @id = SecureRandom.hex(16)
      @data = stringify_keys(session)
      @loaded = true
    end

    def exists?
      true
    end

    def keys
      @data.keys
    end

    def values
      @data.values
    end

    def destroy
      clear
    end

    def fetch(key, *args, &block)
      @data.fetch(key.to_s, *args, &block)
    end

    private

      def load!
        @id
      end
  end

  # Superclass for ActionController functional tests. Functional tests allow you to
  # test a single controller action per test method. This should not be confused with
  # integration tests (see ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest), which are more like
  # "stories" that can involve multiple controllers and multiple actions (i.e. multiple
  # different HTTP requests).
  #
  # == Basic example
  #
  # Functional tests are written as follows:
  # 1. First, one uses the +get+, +post+, +patch+, +put+, +delete+ or +head+ method to simulate
  #    an HTTP request.
  # 2. Then, one asserts whether the current state is as expected. "State" can be anything:
  #    the controller's HTTP response, the database contents, etc.
  #
  # For example:
  #
  #   class BooksControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  #     def test_create
  #       # Simulate a POST response with the given HTTP parameters.
  #       post(:create, params: { book: { title: "Love Hina" }})
  #
  #       # Asserts that the controller tried to redirect us to
  #       # the created book's URI.
  #       assert_response :found
  #
  #       # Asserts that the controller really put the book in the database.
  #       assert_not_nil Book.find_by(title: "Love Hina")
  #     end
  #   end
  #
  # You can also send a real document in the simulated HTTP request.
  #
  #   def test_create
  #     json = {book: { title: "Love Hina" }}.to_json
  #     post :create, json
  #   end
  #
  # == Special instance variables
  #
  # ActionController::TestCase will also automatically provide the following instance
  # variables for use in the tests:
  #
  # <b>@controller</b>::
  #      The controller instance that will be tested.
  # <b>@request</b>::
  #      An ActionController::TestRequest, representing the current HTTP
  #      request. You can modify this object before sending the HTTP request. For example,
  #      you might want to set some session properties before sending a GET request.
  # <b>@response</b>::
  #      An ActionDispatch::TestResponse object, representing the response
  #      of the last HTTP response. In the above example, <tt>@response</tt> becomes valid
  #      after calling +post+. If the various assert methods are not sufficient, then you
  #      may use this object to inspect the HTTP response in detail.
  #
  # (Earlier versions of \Rails required each functional test to subclass
  # Test::Unit::TestCase and define @controller, @request, @response in +setup+.)
  #
  # == Controller is automatically inferred
  #
  # ActionController::TestCase will automatically infer the controller under test
  # from the test class name. If the controller cannot be inferred from the test
  # class name, you can explicitly set it with +tests+.
  #
  #   class SpecialEdgeCaseWidgetsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  #     tests WidgetController
  #   end
  #
  # == \Testing controller internals
  #
  # In addition to these specific assertions, you also have easy access to various collections that the regular test/unit assertions
  # can be used against. These collections are:
  #
  # * session: Objects being saved in the session.
  # * flash: The flash objects currently in the session.
  # * cookies: \Cookies being sent to the user on this request.
  #
  # These collections can be used just like any other hash:
  #
  #   assert_equal "Dave", cookies[:name] # makes sure that a cookie called :name was set as "Dave"
  #   assert flash.empty? # makes sure that there's nothing in the flash
  #
  # On top of the collections, you have the complete url that a given action redirected to available in <tt>redirect_to_url</tt>.
  #
  # For redirects within the same controller, you can even call follow_redirect and the redirect will be followed, triggering another
  # action call which can then be asserted against.
  #
  # == Manipulating session and cookie variables
  #
  # Sometimes you need to set up the session and cookie variables for a test.
  # To do this just assign a value to the session or cookie collection:
  #
  #   session[:key] = "value"
  #   cookies[:key] = "value"
  #
  # To clear the cookies for a test just clear the cookie collection:
  #
  #   cookies.clear
  #
  # == \Testing named routes
  #
  # If you're using named routes, they can be easily tested using the original named routes' methods straight in the test case.
  #
  #  assert_redirected_to page_url(title: 'foo')
  class TestCase < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    module Behavior
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern
      include ActionDispatch::TestProcess
      include ActiveSupport::Testing::ConstantLookup
      include Rails::Dom::Testing::Assertions

      attr_reader :response, :request

      module ClassMethods

        # Sets the controller class name. Useful if the name can't be inferred from test class.
        # Normalizes +controller_class+ before using.
        #
        #   tests WidgetController
        #   tests :widget
        #   tests 'widget'
        def tests(controller_class)
          case controller_class
          when String, Symbol
            self.controller_class = "#{controller_class.to_s.camelize}Controller".constantize
          when Class
            self.controller_class = controller_class
          else
            raise ArgumentError, "controller class must be a String, Symbol, or Class"
          end
        end

        def controller_class=(new_class)
          self._controller_class = new_class
        end

        def controller_class
          if current_controller_class = self._controller_class
            current_controller_class
          else
            self.controller_class = determine_default_controller_class(name)
          end
        end

        def determine_default_controller_class(name)
          determine_constant_from_test_name(name) do |constant|
            Class === constant && constant < ActionController::Metal
          end
        end
      end

      # Simulate a GET request with the given parameters.
      #
      # - +action+: The controller action to call.
      # - +params+: The hash with HTTP parameters that you want to pass. This may be +nil+.
      # - +body+: The request body with a string that is appropriately encoded
      #   (<tt>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</tt> or <tt>multipart/form-data</tt>).
      # - +session+: A hash of parameters to store in the session. This may be +nil+.
      # - +flash+: A hash of parameters to store in the flash. This may be +nil+.
      #
      # You can also simulate POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, and HEAD requests with
      # +post+, +patch+, +put+, +delete+, and +head+.
      # Example sending parameters, session and setting a flash message:
      #
      #   get :show,
      #     params: { id: 7 },
      #     session: { user_id: 1 },
      #     flash: { notice: 'This is flash message' }
      #
      # Note that the request method is not verified. The different methods are
      # available to make the tests more expressive.
      def get(action, *args)
        res = process_with_kwargs("GET", action, *args)
        cookies.update res.cookies
        res
      end

      # Simulate a POST request with the given parameters and set/volley the response.
      # See +get+ for more details.
      def post(action, *args)
        process_with_kwargs("POST", action, *args)
      end

      # Simulate a PATCH request with the given parameters and set/volley the response.
      # See +get+ for more details.
      def patch(action, *args)
        process_with_kwargs("PATCH", action, *args)
      end

      # Simulate a PUT request with the given parameters and set/volley the response.
      # See +get+ for more details.
      def put(action, *args)
        process_with_kwargs("PUT", action, *args)
      end

      # Simulate a DELETE request with the given parameters and set/volley the response.
      # See +get+ for more details.
      def delete(action, *args)
        process_with_kwargs("DELETE", action, *args)
      end

      # Simulate a HEAD request with the given parameters and set/volley the response.
      # See +get+ for more details.
      def head(action, *args)
        process_with_kwargs("HEAD", action, *args)
      end

      def xml_http_request(*args)
        ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn(<<-MSG.strip_heredoc)
          xhr and xml_http_request methods are deprecated in favor of
          `get :index, xhr: true` and `post :create, xhr: true`
        MSG

        @request.env['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'
        @request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT'] ||= [Mime[:js], Mime[:html], Mime[:xml], 'text/xml', '*/*'].join(', ')
        __send__(*args).tap do
          @request.env.delete 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'
          @request.env.delete 'HTTP_ACCEPT'
        end
      end
      alias xhr :xml_http_request

      # Simulate an HTTP request to +action+ by specifying request method,
      # parameters and set/volley the response.
      #
      # - +action+: The controller action to call.
      # - +method+: Request method used to send the HTTP request. Possible values
      #   are +GET+, +POST+, +PATCH+, +PUT+, +DELETE+, +HEAD+. Defaults to +GET+. Can be a symbol.
      # - +params+: The hash with HTTP parameters that you want to pass. This may be +nil+.
      # - +body+: The request body with a string that is appropriately encoded
      #   (<tt>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</tt> or <tt>multipart/form-data</tt>).
      # - +session+: A hash of parameters to store in the session. This may be +nil+.
      # - +flash+: A hash of parameters to store in the flash. This may be +nil+.
      # - +format+: Request format. Defaults to +nil+. Can be string or symbol.
      #
      # Example calling +create+ action and sending two params:
      #
      #   process :create,
      #     method: 'POST',
      #     params: {
      #       user: { name: 'Gaurish Sharma', email: 'user@example.com' }
      #     },
      #     session: { user_id: 1 },
      #     flash: { notice: 'This is flash message' }
      #
      # To simulate +GET+, +POST+, +PATCH+, +PUT+, +DELETE+ and +HEAD+ requests
      # prefer using #get, #post, #patch, #put, #delete and #head methods
      # respectively which will make tests more expressive.
      #
      # Note that the request method is not verified.
      def process(action, *args)
        check_required_ivars

        if kwarg_request?(args)
          parameters, session, body, flash, http_method, format, xhr = args[0].values_at(:params, :session, :body, :flash, :method, :format, :xhr)
        else
          http_method, parameters, session, flash = args
          format = nil

          if parameters.is_a?(String) && http_method != 'HEAD'
            body = parameters
            parameters = nil
          end

          if parameters || session || flash
            non_kwarg_request_warning
          end
        end

        if body
          @request.set_header 'RAW_POST_DATA', body
        end

        if http_method
          http_method = http_method.to_s.upcase
        else
          http_method = "GET"
        end

        parameters ||= {}

        if format
          parameters[:format] = format
        end

        @html_document = nil

        self.cookies.update @request.cookies
        self.cookies.update_cookies_from_jar
        @request.set_header 'HTTP_COOKIE', cookies.to_header
        @request.delete_header 'action_dispatch.cookies'

        @request          = TestRequest.new scrub_env!(@request.env, @request.session)
        @response         = build_response @response_klass
        @response.request = @request
        @controller.recycle!

        @request.set_header 'REQUEST_METHOD', http_method

        parameters = parameters.symbolize_keys

        generated_extras = @routes.generate_extras(parameters.merge(controller: controller_class_name, action: action.to_s))
        generated_path = generated_path(generated_extras)
        query_string_keys = query_parameter_names(generated_extras)

        @request.assign_parameters(@routes, controller_class_name, action.to_s, parameters, generated_path, query_string_keys)

        @request.session.update(session) if session
        @request.flash.update(flash || {})

        if xhr
          @request.set_header 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH', 'XMLHttpRequest'
          @request.fetch_header('HTTP_ACCEPT') do |k|
            @request.set_header k, [Mime[:js], Mime[:html], Mime[:xml], 'text/xml', '*/*'].join(', ')
          end
        end

        @request.fetch_header("SCRIPT_NAME") do |k|
          @request.set_header k, @controller.config.relative_url_root
        end

        begin
          @controller.recycle!
          @controller.dispatch(action, @request, @response)
        ensure
          @request = @controller.request
          @response = @controller.response

          @request.delete_header 'HTTP_COOKIE'

          if @request.have_cookie_jar?
            unless @request.cookie_jar.committed?
              @request.cookie_jar.write(@response)
              self.cookies.update(@request.cookie_jar.instance_variable_get(:@cookies))
            end
          end
          @response.prepare!

          if flash_value = @request.flash.to_session_value
            @request.session['flash'] = flash_value
          else
            @request.session.delete('flash')
          end

          if xhr
            @request.delete_header 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'
            @request.delete_header 'HTTP_ACCEPT'
          end
          @request.query_string = ''

          @response.sent!
        end

        @response
      end

      def controller_class_name
        @controller.class.anonymous? ? "anonymous" : @controller.class.controller_path
      end

      def generated_path(generated_extras)
        generated_extras[0]
      end

      def query_parameter_names(generated_extras)
        generated_extras[1] + [:controller, :action]
      end

      def setup_controller_request_and_response
        @controller = nil unless defined? @controller

        @response_klass = ActionDispatch::TestResponse

        if klass = self.class.controller_class
          if klass < ActionController::Live
            @response_klass = LiveTestResponse
          end
          unless @controller
            begin
              @controller = klass.new
            rescue
              warn "could not construct controller #{klass}" if $VERBOSE
            end
          end
        end

        @request          = TestRequest.create
        @response         = build_response @response_klass
        @response.request = @request

        if @controller
          @controller.request = @request
          @controller.params = {}
        end
      end

      def build_response(klass)
        klass.create
      end

      included do
        include ActionController::TemplateAssertions
        include ActionDispatch::Assertions
        class_attribute :_controller_class
        setup :setup_controller_request_and_response
      end

      private

      def scrub_env!(env)
        env.delete_if { |k, v| k =~ /^(action_dispatch|rack)\.request/ }
        env.delete_if { |k, v| k =~ /^action_dispatch\.rescue/ }
        env.delete 'action_dispatch.request.query_parameters'
        env.delete 'action_dispatch.request.request_parameters'
        env
      end

      def process_with_kwargs(http_method, action, *args)
        if kwarg_request?(args)
          args.first.merge!(method: http_method)
          process(action, *args)
        else
          non_kwarg_request_warning if args.any?

          args = args.unshift(http_method)
          process(action, *args)
        end
      end

      REQUEST_KWARGS = %i(params session flash method body xhr)
      def kwarg_request?(args)
        args[0].respond_to?(:keys) && (
          (args[0].key?(:format) && args[0].keys.size == 1) ||
          args[0].keys.any? { |k| REQUEST_KWARGS.include?(k) }
        )
      end

      def non_kwarg_request_warning
        ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn(<<-MSG.strip_heredoc)
          ActionController::TestCase HTTP request methods will accept only
          keyword arguments in future Rails versions.

          Examples:

          get :show, params: { id: 1 }, session: { user_id: 1 }
          process :update, method: :post, params: { id: 1 }
        MSG
      end

      def document_root_element
        html_document.root
      end

      def check_required_ivars
        # Sanity check for required instance variables so we can give an
        # understandable error message.
        [:@routes, :@controller, :@request, :@response].each do |iv_name|
          if !instance_variable_defined?(iv_name) || instance_variable_get(iv_name).nil?
            raise "#{iv_name} is nil: make sure you set it in your test's setup method."
          end
        end
      end

      def html_format?(parameters)
        return true unless parameters.key?(:format)
        Mime.fetch(parameters[:format]) { Mime['html'] }.html?
      end
    end

    include Behavior
  end
  # :startdoc:
end
```

Here is the error when I run rake db:migrate:

rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport
/Users/my_username/projects/zoner/config/application.rb:1:in `

Here is the application.rb file's first lines:

```
ActiveSupport.halt_callback_chains_on_return_false = false

require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)


require File.expand_path('../initializers/decent_exposure', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext'
```

If there is someone that can help identify the errors in this code that will help me add the necessary arguments to the TestRequest class that would be very helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: for rake db:migrate - in Rails 5 it's now all rails db:migrate command, no more rake for less confusion

Comment: As for the first error, give full stack trace to understand there the call is coming from. Otherwise, it's not clear what is the reason behind what you described (0 args instead of expected 2).

Comment: Did you find [this](https://github.com/drapergem/draper/issues/698) question? Are you using draper gem?

Comment: Thank you @Paul Bulanov, I am reviewing your link to [Draper gem issue #698](https://github.com/drapergem/draper/issues/698).  Also reviewing this issue [Draper issue #681](https://github.com/drapergem/draper/issues/681)

Comment: After correcting myself, replacing rake with rails db:migrate I receive the following error: rails aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rails/test_unit/sub_test_task

Comment: As for Draper thing, based on its repository the issue is _not_ resolved in master branch. So you won't get it working "out-of-the-box" with draper. You can pick up simple fix commit from one of the rails5 branches referenced in the issue.

Comment: Get out of draper and see if rails console will work for you

Comment: https://github.com/drapergem/draper/issues/681

Comment: see my answer - try using `rails-5` branch of diaper, which is being updated right now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update** from @scott-w (August 2016):

> The correct location is now: `gem 'draper', github: 'drapergem/draper'`
>
> the rails-5 branch has been merged into master and no longer exists

**Original**: The issue with rails console error is caused by `draper` gem as seen from the trace. As it stands now, master (main) branch of draper doesn't support Rails 5. It seems to be know for some long time, but before Rails 5 was officially released as stable, it wasn't really put action on.

Try this fork with few fixes embedded ("old" solution)

```
gem 'draper', github: 'audionerd/draper', branch: 'rails5'
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/drapergem/draper/issues/681)

Or better (seems to become current solution)

```
gem 'draper', github: 'drapergem/draper', branch: 'rails-5'
```

The work on this kind of official branch is going as we speak :) 
https://github.com/drapergem/draper/commits/rails-5

Or get rid of draper for Rails 5, as it doesn't support it in its master branch *yet* (seems to change in the coming days)

*Update* -> rails-5 branch was merged into master so Rails 5 are now supported

Comment: Thank you @Pavel Bulanov, rails console working now!  Have an issue with migrations because the duplicate column with ActiveAdmin tables but will work on this fix or continue editing this post.  Thank you again!

Comment: The gem 'draper', github: 'drapergem/draper', branch: 'rails-5' did the trick but still having trouble with migrations.  Looking for answers with this new post - [Ruby on Rails 5.0 upgrade with migrating users table conflicts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38193075/ruby-on-rails-5-0-upgrade-with-migrating-users-table-conflicts)

Comment: The correct location is now: gem 'draper', github: 'drapergem/draper' (the rails-5 branch has been merged into master and no longer exists)