# Rails 5 Upgrade : /actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:49:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (0 for 2) (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am recently working through a Rails 5 upgrade, and am running into this error when I try to fire up the rails console:

`/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:49:in initialize': wrong number of arguments (0 for 2) (ArgumentError)`

Currently `bundle update rails` has finished with gem dependencies resolved enough to to do the update to 5.0.0, rspec is running (albeit with a lot of breaks I am fixing). I can also run `rails s` without an error.

Here is the line of code breaking:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb

Full stack:

`` /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:49:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (0 for 2) (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/draper-2.1.0/lib/draper/view_context/build_strategy.rb:41:in `new'
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/draper-2.1.0/lib/draper/view_context/build_strategy.rb:41:in `block in controller'
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/draper-2.1.0/lib/draper/view_context/build_strategy.rb:40:in `tap'
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/draper-2.1.0/lib/draper/view_context/build_strategy.rb:40:in `controller'
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/draper-2.1.0/lib/draper/view_context/build_strategy.rb:30:in `call'
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/draper-2.1.0/lib/draper/view_context.rb:49:in `build'
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/draper-2.1.0/lib/draper/railtie.rb:63:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:226:in `call'
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:226:in `block in run_console_blocks'
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:247:in `each'
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:247:in `each_registered_block'
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:226:in `run_console_blocks'
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:463:in `block in run_console_blocks'
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:13:in `each'
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:13:in `each'
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:463:in `run_console_blocks'
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:442:in `load_console'
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:34:in `initialize'
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `new'
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/this_is_my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>' ``

Comment: Redundant question, solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188968/ruby-on-rails-5-0-upgrade-not-working-with-rails-console-or-dbmigrate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kudos to Scott W.

Issue *mostly* answered here: [Ruby on Rails 5.0 upgrade not working with rails console or db:migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188968/ruby-on-rails-5-0-upgrade-not-working-with-rails-console-or-dbmigrate)

I want to clarify that `gem 'draper', github: 'drapergem/draper', branch: 'rails-5'` no longer works, but `gem 'draper', github: 'audionerd/draper', branch: 'rails5'` did work to fix this error.

Comment: You can also use the `3.0.0.pre1` release version of draper, for Rails 5 support.