# Rails console crashes with error : wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2) (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-console

i am using ruby version 2.3.1 and rails version 5.0.0

When i try to run rails console and i get error as follows

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:49:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2) (ArgumentError)
```

Can you please suggest any solution to get rid of this error as i cannot run rails console.

Full error trace is

```
rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:49:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2) (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/bilkhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/draper-2.1.0/lib/draper/view_context/build_strategy.rb:41:in `new'
    from /Users/bilkhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/draper-2.1.0/lib/draper/view_context/build_strategy.rb:41:in `block in controller'
    from /Users/bilkhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/draper-2.1.0/lib/draper/view_context/build_strategy.rb:40:in `tap'
    from /Users/bilkhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/draper-2.1.0/lib/draper/view_context/build_strategy.rb:40:in `controller'
    from /Users/bilkhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/draper-2.1.0/lib/draper/view_context/build_strategy.rb:30:in `call'
    from /Users/bilkhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/draper-2.1.0/lib/draper/view_context.rb:49:in `build'
    from /Users/bilkhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/draper-2.1.0/lib/draper/railtie.rb:63:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/bilkhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:226:in `block in run_console_blocks'
    from /Users/bilkhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:247:in `each'
    from /Users/bilkhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:247:in `each_registered_block'
    from /Users/bilkhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:226:in `run_console_blocks'
    from /Users/bilkhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:463:in `block in run_console_blocks'
    from /Users/bilkhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:13:in `each'
    from /Users/bilkhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:13:in `each'
    from /Users/bilkhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:463:in `run_console_blocks'
    from /Users/bilkhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:442:in `load_console'
    from /Users/bilkhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:34:in `initialize'
    from /Users/bilkhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `new'
    from /Users/bilkhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/bilkhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /Users/bilkhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/bilkhan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please show the full error trace, not just the single line.

Comment: I have edited my question with error trace.

Answer (score 1):

You might be running draper gem ?

Look at [Ruby on Rails 5.0 upgrade not working with rails console or db:migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188968/ruby-on-rails-5-0-upgrade-not-working-with-rails-console-or-dbmigrate)

There's an issue between Draper and Rails 5.
Use the master branch

> ```
> The correct location is now: gem 'draper', github: 'drapergem/draper'
> the rails-5 branch has been merged into master and no longer exists
> ```